# Do newer versions of Linux use a different include than libata-core.h?

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, ata

I am trying to compile a module that includes libata-core.h as follows:

```
#include <linux/drivers/ata/libata-core.h>
```

on debian Jessie. The compiler says "No such file or directory". I have the kernel source and headers installed and some of those including "scripts/Makefile.build" are found in this compile so I think the include paths are correct. find agrees that there's no such file. Did the name change? The module uses a number of functions like ata_qc_new_init() which were defined in this file (at least in the web accessible versions of the file). These now seem to be defined in :

```
linux/drivers/ata/libata.h
```

is that the correct include to use?

Answer (score 1):

Debian distribution does not contain "libata-core.h" file at all.

You can easily check this on https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages page.

So using of libata.h from linux-headers-xxx package is the only way.